# Wordpress and mysql : Issue with trigger

Tags: mysql, wordpress, insert, sql-update, database-trigger

Excuse me if I am wrong place to post, I am new and french (sorry for my modified google translate), usually I still manage but there I break my teeth on this problem.

I'm working on WordPress, MySQL and with a member management plugin named WP-member. I modified the plugin to be able to make that the user enters his postal code.

The problem is that with WordPress all the information concerning the users is stored in the usermeta table.

Here is the structure of the table:
`umeta_id` (pk): is not the id of the user but the id of the registration ie it can be the name of the user, his postal code etc. Several `umeta_id` can be affiliated with the id of the user.

`user_id` (fk): is the id of the user, it is pk in another table but the other table can not store the data that I want because the table is not modifiable under WordPress.

meta_key: is the title of the data, for example name, zip code. So we can find several times the same meta_key for different users.

meta_value: answer to the meta_key, that's where it finds the saved data.

example of a simplified user:

```
umeta_id | user_id | meta_key   | meta_value
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1        |   1     | name        | Toto

2        |   1     | postcode    | 66000

...      |   1     | ...         | ...

15       |   1     | city        | Perpignan
```

The problem with this structure is that I think the more users will accumulate the more the requests to retrieve postal codes will be long.

Because for a user there can be 15 different recordings. If there are 10000 users there will be 150000 rows to go to retrieve the zip codes that we want. I would like to have your opinion because I think the structure of this table is problematic.

So I want to create a new user table with a structure that looks like this (I do not need the city) to facilitate queries and probably their response time.

```
user_id | name  | postcode
-----------------------------------
   1    | toto  | 66000
```

For the creation of the table no worries, regarding to implement it via trigger from the table `usermeta` I can only get the `user_id` and the name thanks to the call of `new.user_id` but I can not retrieve the zip code. Trigger below:

```
insert into users (user_id, name, codepostal) values ​​(
   (select distinct user_id from usermeta where user_id = new.user_id),
   (select meta_value from te_usermeta where meta_key = 'name' and user_id = new.user_id),
   (select meta_value from te_usermeta where meta_key = 'codepostal' and user_id = new.user_id)
 )
```

I tell myself that an update will be worse. Can someone guide me? I thank you in advance.

Comment: So you are assuming it will be slow and want to change a very fundamental thing about how wordpress works (the EAV-model is used very heavily in wordpress). You probably should not do that. And especially if you just retrieve a single information, EAV (with proper indexes) shouldn't be slower than your other query. Also, 150k rows is really not much data andm ight accumulate to some MB, which will fit nicely in your cache/memory (which is usually measured in GB). If it *is* slow, you should add some details (especially the output of `explain yourquery`, you might then have a missing index).

Comment: Hello Solarflare i answer my question with a question for you

Answer (score 0):

i don't know but on another site they give me this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `ajouter`
BEFORE insert ON `tabone`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE _name         VARCHAR(255)  DEFAULT NULL;
  DECLARE _postcode  INTEGER       DEFAULT NULL;

  SET _name        = (select name        from `tabtwo` where user_id = new.user_id);
  SET _postcode = (select postcode from `tabtwo` where user_id = new.user_id);

  IF new.meta_key = 'name'        then replace into `tabtwo` (`user_id`,`name`,`postcode`) values (new.user_id, new.meta_value,_postcode); END IF;
  IF new.meta_key = 'postcode' then replace into `tabtwo` (`user_id`,`name`,`postcode`) values (new.user_id,_name,new.meta_value);         END IF;
```

and it works.

How will a query on a new table optimized with indexs be slower than a query on a table of an unstructured wordpress EAV model?